# Cant get a valid payload due to a too large string (base64 image)

Tags: java, android, base64

I make a http request in my android app to the google cloud api with the Volley library. My problem resides in the payload that I am sending. Google returns an 400 error. If I manually create the payload (json file) it works just fine.

I am creating a JSONObject and put into imageBytes the string "[BASE64]". If I put in the base64 encoded string directly i get escape problems as soon as I do JSONObject.toString().

Here is my code:

```
JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
JSONObject image = new JSONObject();
JSONObject imageBytes = new JSONObject();

imageBytes.put("imageBytes", "[BASE64]");
image.put("image", imageBytes);
payload.put("payload", image);

requestBody = payload.toString().replace("[BASE64]", convert_bitmap(args[0]));

private String convert_bitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

I also tried to load the example payload file and replace the [BASE64] with my base64 string getting the same result. The only thing that works is adding the base64 encoded image directly in

```
imageBytes.put("imageBytes", "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA...");
```

but only if the image is very small. I get compiler error (String is too long) when I put a large string there.
I have also tried to send the request to my server and save it in order to see differences between the working one and mine. The only thing that I have noticed is that in the non working examples, the line length is shorter:

```
{"payload":{"image":{"imageBytes":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAIQAABtbnRyUkdC
IFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA9tYAAQAA
AADTLQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAlk
ZXNjAAAA8AAAAHRyWFlaAAABZAAAABRnWFlaAAABeAAAABRiWFlaAAABjAAAABRyVFJDAAABoAAA..."}}}
```

and the working one:

```
{"payload":{"image":{"imageBytes":"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..."}}}
```

Resuming: When I add the base64 encoded image directly into the json file I get it to work. Also when I convert a very small image file into base64 and put the string directly into my code it works. But when dealing with normal images (photo taken with phone etc) and put the base64 encoded string in the imageBytes field it wont work due to escape problems (toString() seems to add slashes when converting the JSONObject) and replacing something like [BASE64] with my string also doesnt work due to line breaks or string length limits. I expect my problem to be here but cant solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Oh boy… I have solved it! The solution was the `Base64.NO_WRAP` flag.
As I already thought while posting my question, the problem was the line break added while converting to base64.